# Supporting multiple resolutions in MonoGame Windows 8 XAML app

Tags: windows-8, xna, winrt-xaml, monogame

I am writing a Windows 8 game using MonoGame 3.01 and SwapChainBackgroundPanel to integrate with XAML.
My assets are optimized for 16:9 aspect ratio, though I need to support 4:3 as well due to variations in Win8 device resolutions.

Currently I face following problems:

1. Dragging the game to a second monitor does not resize the screen

   ```
       _graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = (int)width;
       _graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = (int)height;
       _graphics.ApplyChanges();
   ```

In SwapChainBackgroundPanel (GamePage) I react to size changes

```
    void GamePage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Game.SetBackBuffer(e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height);
    }
```

But nothing happens, seems like only the initial (after the game is initialized) back buffer change is applied.

1. Is there a way to preserve aspect ratio instead of stretching to fill, eg. by letterboxing?

What is the best practice to support multiple resolutions on Windows 8 (including Snapped view)?

EDIT: Just to clarify - GamePage_SizeChanged is being executed its just _graphics.ApplyChanges() that seems to have no effect

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding the Client Size Changed Event into your Game constructor.

Example:

```
public Game1()
{
    _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    this.Windows.ClientSizeChanged += Window_ClientSizeChanged;
}

void Window_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentWidth = this.Window.ClientBounds.Width;
    int currentHeight = this.Windows.ClientBounds.Height;
}
```

You can also add an event handler for ApplicationViewChanged to detect the Snapped, Filled, and Full ViewStates by comparing the ViewChangeArgs to the ApplicationViewState enumeration in Windows8.  You have access to the SwapChainBackgroundPanel of your game from _graphics.SwapChainPanel property. Finally, you also have _graphics.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode with has AspectRatio, Height, Width.

Comment: Thanks, I know where to react to size changes but the problem is that changing PreferredBackBufferWidth has no effect. And I do not know how to make content scale preserving aspect ratio without doing manual transformations
.

Comment: For Windows 8 PreferredBufferWidth is preset in MonoGame to 1366, 760. You have access to the current GraphicDevice and event handlers for start & end DeviceChanging so you should be able to change the Device size there.  Let me test changing this in my game and I will post the code.